# What kind of change detection strategy is being used in Kendo?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In our application we prefer the "on-push" strategy for all of our UI components for performance reasons.
(changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush)
We are considering using Kendo for some of the UI components (mainly grid but some others as well) and then it occured to us that we don't know what Kendo is doing internally.
Does it use default or on-push change detection?

Comment: pretty sure the use the default change detection strategy, they kinda have to, since the dont know how people are going to use the grid

Comment: @Ron Grosberg Did you find out what they are using. I am evaluatin this control and wanted more info. If you can please can you let me know. Cheers

Comment: Nope.... I assume Nick is correct, they probably use the default change detection otherwise it won't always work for everyone (those who don't understand the on-push)..... but I have no real evidence

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/2876), most Kendo UI components use the default change detection strategy, but there are some exceptions: Charts, Date Inputs, Scheduler, TreeList and some internal components use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.